# Cannot read or decode UDP packet in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, broadcast

I'm trying to read UDP Broadcast messages sent by an device in my network on port 2009. I can see Python receives data from the device, but it's in Bytes. I have tried to decode it with .decode() or .hex(), also with ignore errors,  but it's still not "readable".

All I get from the machine is:

```
b' \x08\x19\x96VDLG\x03\xac\x11P\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01@0\x00\x0bZ'
```

The code is (very basic):

```
import socket
import codecs

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
client.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEPORT, 1)
client.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)

client.bind(("", 2009))
while True:
    data, addr = client.recvfrom(8192)
    print(data)
```

Maybe someone with a little bit more experience reading broadcast can shed a light for me, because all I try fails.

It should read something like this:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Well, that's the message received. You did not tell us the source, but in general theses messages do not need to be readable text. To the computer they are just bytes unless you tell it how to decode.

Comment: It can be decoded back to somewhat readable contents, as I've seen with many applications that do so. Only I don't know how and any attempt to decode/parse it makes it worse 

Comment: Well, that's what the developer has to know / find out. We can't do that for you without any information.

Comment: I've added a picture with output of the application which can read the packets

Comment: You want to get a whole bunch of these packets, get the raw data from Python and also the human-readable data from the application. Then try and figure out the pattern. You probably do want to make your Python program print in binary or hexadecimal, instead of the default, which is ASCII with escape codes.